# Drools recursive rules not firing

Tags: recursion, drools

I took the Fibanocci example and modified it little bit. It still seems to work, but I don't know how. Here is my rule.

```
rule "Recurse"
salience 10
    when
       f : Fibanocci(value == 0)
       not Fibanocci(sequence == 0)
    then
       System.out.println(f.sequence + "/" + f.value);
       insert(new Fibanocci(f.sequence - 1));
end
```

I get the following output:

50/0
49/0
48/0
47/0 
46/0 
45/0 
.. and so on

It seems to me every time a new instance of `Fibanocci` is inserted, it should start from 50 again, but it doesn't.

```
// here is my class, getter/setter skipped
public class Fibonacci {

    private int sequence;
    private long value;

    public Fibonacci(final int sequence) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short explanation, why the rules fire like they do:

- Every rule fires exactly once for any combination of matching working memory elements.
- The first match is generated by *"a Fibonacci-Object with value==0"* and *"the non-existance of a Fibonacci-Object with sequence==0"*.
- For this combination, the rule will **not fire again** until

  - the particular Fibonacci-Object is modified and updated.
  - a Fibonacci-Object with sequence==0 appears and then disappears (*)
- The consequence of the rule creates another Fibonacci-Object with value==0. This creates only one more match of *"a Fibonacci-Object with value==0"* and *"the non-existance of a Fibonacci-Object with sequence==0"*. (The "non-existance" fact is not changed.)

*) only 99% sure about that